# Angular run only one of two functions

Tags: html, angular, function

Is that possible to have two functions inside HTML element but to run only one of them according to a condition? for example:

```
<Button (click)="aFunction() ? anotherFucntion()">Hi</Button>
```

Comment: so use a ternary operator? Or call a function and have that function determine what to do.

Comment: "ternary operator" is the name I was looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want someThing Like This

```
export class AppComponent {
      someFlag: boolean = false;
      firstFunction() {
        console.log('hi i am from first Function');
      }
      secondFunction() {
        console.log('hi i am from Second Function');
      }
    }

<button (click)="someFlag ? firstFunction() : secondFunction()">Hi</button>
```

but i would prefer if the code in the Component Like This

```
  doTheWork() {
    return this.someFlag ? this.firstFunction() : this.secondFunction();
  }
```

and then just call it in the html Like this

```
<button (click)="doTheWork()">Hi</button>
```

you can test the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-esgevs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)